# Import modules from parent folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to access the contents of a module (fileB.py) from a file (fileA.py) that is in another directory. I tried the following code in fileA.py:

```
from ..subpackageB import fileB
```

However, I get the error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

The structure of the project is similar to this:

```
toplevel_package/
├── file.py
└── subpackageA
    └── fileA.py
└── subpackageB
    ├── __init__.py
    └── fileB.py
```

The __init__.py file is empty

Comment: How did you run ``fileA``?

Comment: python3 fileA.py

Comment: Run it as ``python3 -m toplevel_package.subpackageA.fileA`` from the root folder that contains ``toplevel_package``.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyCharm you can mark the `subpackageB` as a source root, then remove the dotes.

See examples [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-content-roots.html#specify-folder-categories).

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to your `toplevel_package` folder path.
Once done, any import statement will "start" from this location.
You can then do:

```
from subpackageB import fileB
```

Another way is to add you project root to sys.path eg `sys.path.insert(0, 'toplevel_package_path')` but this requires to do this in all your scripts before importing any of your modules.

Answer (score -1):

This can be a little tricky

```
import os,sys
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..')) 
from subpackageB import fileB
```

Read this https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path should be helpful.

Comment: ``sys.path`` should *not* be modified like this. It can lead to various module being duplicated, e.g. ``fileA.py`` existing separately as the modules ``fileA`` and ``subpackageA.fileA``. These duplicates are not interchangeable, and various things such as identity or instance testing as well as exception handling will fail when mixing objects/types from the separate modules.